# Remove background video buffering process

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, mediaelement.js

Following is my piece of code which I am using to remove all the created players. The code works fine but the issue I am facing is that the video after changing via ajax call success keep on buffering as background process. Kindly let me know how can I kill that background process as well so it should not buffer the video in background. I am using `mediaelementjs` plugin for my html5 video.

```
var player;
        $('video').each(function() {
            player = $(this)[0].player;
            player.remove();
        });
```

Comment: try setting the video tag's .src (or it's tracks) to "about:"blank" before remove()ing it.

Comment: how did you create the player? (show the code)

Comment: @JFK `$('video').mediaelementplayer();`

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws me an error but you could try instead :

```
$('video').each(function (i) {
    $("#mep_" + i).remove();
});
```

I don't see further buffering after this.

Comment: **NOTE**: if the issue is after ajax success, then show your full code, otherwise we don't have enough information to diagnostic the problem.

Comment: Buffering in the background is not stopping at all. Your code worked in a way when I clicked then the player disappeared and re initiate for the clicked video and the old video was buffered to `30 seconds` when I switched back after some time to that old (last played) video, then its was buffered up to 2 minutes. I am completely blank why is it happening I hope its happening at your end too if you are switching between videos via ajax. My preload is set to `none` but its not a point when I have already removed that video element.

Comment: Note: I clicked on another video when the current video was in playing state.

Comment: Well, I think it's a matter of the browser (each browser has different buffering mechanisms) rather than MEJS and I am not sure you can really control that in an uniformed way.

Comment: I managed to stop it by `  window.mejs = null; window.MediaElement = null; window.MediaElementPlayer = null;` but after this the mediaelement is not re initiating by `$('video').mediaelementplayer();` kindly hel how to deal with it?